# How to pause windows operations in dotnet or java

Tags: java, .net, windows, operating-system, ubuntu-16.04

I am developing a application like whenever bluetooth is connected to the system works fine otherwise it pause operations and show connect bluetooth window.after reconnect then the system works fine.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable design, sure.

Comment: Actually my application is like this. System and mobile is connected to bluetooth if bluetooth is in connected with mobile then only the user can access the system otherwise it show a window of "connect bluetooth to access" and connect button. I thought to write code in java or .net .

Comment: .net would be preferred.. use windows scheduler to scheduling your programs. check Minute wise whether Bluetooth is connected or not ? if not connected then display message. disable close & minimize buttons of app window. if reconnected then close it automatically. even you can lock the system automatically when Bluetooth gets disconnected. You may stop some services and start automatically (If you have admin rights on system or run app as administrator rights).

Comment: thank you mahadev mane sir. please give some links of any code for stop and start services in .net. and also for windows scheduler. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing operations with specific application then you may start and stop the application process or services & show such notifications / dialog window in Windows.

Comment: Actually my application is like this. System and mobile is connected to bluetooth if bluetooth is in connected with mobile then only the user can access the system otherwise it show a window of "connect bluetooth to access" and connect button. I thought to write code in java or .net .